# Infinitivos terminados em -ri

Tags: verbos, mudanças-históricas

Estava escutando o novo disco dum grupo de música tradicional portuguesa, e numa das canções a forma do infinitivo não é a normal de *-ar/er/ir* senão *-ari/eri/iri*:

> Extracto da letra para [«Lá cima ó castelo» de *Seiva*](http://amusicaportuguesa.blogs.sapo.pt/la-cima-o-castelo-seiva-1671464)
>
> Já não há não há, já não pode haveri.
> Vinho na caneca pra gente buêri.
> Pra genti bueri pra gente pagari,
> Já não há não há quem mande ir deitari

Obviamente, assim era a forma no latim e no romance (embora com *-are/ere/ire*) que se pode encontrar mesmo hoje nuns dialectos de asturiano e castelhano.

Esta forma conserva-se nalgum dialecto moderno do português ou fica agora totalmente extinto?

Comment: (guifa, deves gostar de "A Música Portuguesa a Gostar Dela Própria". Procura por isso.)

Comment: (Por certo, o vocablo *buer* parece um trasmontanismo que significa *beber*) @ANever obrigadíssimo! As sugestões que me dão Google e iTunes não servem muito bem para encontrar nova música deste tipo.

Comment: Sim, há algumas zonas de Portugal onde se fala com esse sotaque. (Eu não tenho grandes certezas; por isso não consigo escrever uma resposta.)

Comment: Lembro-me duma pessoa do sul (alentejano) que por vezes adicionava esse _i_ no final dos verbos no infinitivo. Também encontrei um [vídeo dos "Malucos do Riso"](https://youtu.be/DsiNdeuU0J8?t=323) em que isso acontece.

Comment: Também se dizia *buer* em vez de *beber* na zona de Torres Vedras, a uns 50 km a norte de Lisboa.

Comment: Na comunidade piscatória de Ovar também se acrescenta o i ao infinitivo de muitos verbos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Palavras terminadas em "ri" são normalmente reconhecidas em tempos modernos como parte do sotaque Alentejano (mais acentuado nas zonas entre Beja e Évora).
Este não foi sempre o caso, em tempos mais antigos este tipo de dicção estava espalhado desde a zona de Castelo Branco (possivelmente até Fundão) até à fronteira natural entre o Alentejo e Algarve pelas serras de Monchique e Caldeirão. A canção citada tem origem numa canção tradicional da zona da Beira-Baixa, e a versão do Seiva não se desvia muito do original.

Abaixo estão dois links, o primeiro contém comentários sobre a própria musica e o segundo para uma outra musica de origem similar e com o mesmo tipo de palavras.

http://diferencial.tecnico.pt/2015/11/04/tradicao-um-legado-que-reflete-o-contexto-sociopolitico/
http://www.memoriamedia.net/bd_docs/Transcricoes_Idanha_a_nova/zamburra.pdf